A Normal Distribution of Normal Distributions
This question is a follow-up question from Law of Large Numbers for Changing Distributions
Suppose I have a Random Variable $X$ such that:
$$ X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$$
$$ \mu \sim N(\theta_1, \theta_2)$$
$$ \sigma \sim N(\theta_3, \theta_4)$$
I am interested in finding out :

The Expected Value of $X$
The Variance of $X$
The Distribution of $X$

Here is my attempt to do this.
1) Expected Value of X:
From Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation), an informal proof for the Law of Total Expectations is given:
\begin{align}
\operatorname E_x(X) &= \int x \Pr[X=x] ~dx \tag{1} \\
\operatorname E_x(X\mid Y=y) &= \int x \Pr[X=x\mid Y=y] ~dx \tag{2} \\
\operatorname E_y( \operatorname E_x(X\mid Y)) &= \int \left(\int x \Pr[X=x\mid Y=y] ~dx \right) \Pr[Y=y] ~dy \tag{3} \\
&= \int \int x \Pr[X = x, Y= y] ~dx ~dy \tag{4} \\
&= \int x \left( \int \Pr[X = x, Y = y] ~dy \right) ~dx \tag{5} \\
&= \int x \Pr[X = x] ~dx \tag{6} \\
&= \operatorname E(X)\,. \tag{7}
\end{align}
Some remarks on this:

In (2), it took me a while to realize that the result of $ E(X\mid Y=y)$ is actually a function of $Y$. This is because I kept thinking that $P(X | Y=y)$ is a function of $X$.
Going from (3) to (4) uses $P(A|B)\cdot P(B) = P(AB)$ . Thus, $Pr[X=x∣Y=y] \cdot Pr[Y=y] = Pr[X,Y]$
Going from (4) to (5) is a simple order of integration
Going from (5) to (6), we are removing $Y$ through marginalization. Thus we have $Pr(X)$

I tried to then extend this for a second variable:
$$
\begin{align}
E(E(E(X|Y,Z)|Z)) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E(E(X|Y,Z)|Z=z) \cdot f_Z(z) dz \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E(X|Y=y,Z=z) \cdot f_{Y|Z}(y|z) dy\right) \cdot f_Z(z) dz \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f_{X|Y,Z}(x|y,z) dx\right) \cdot f_{Y|Z}(y|z) dy \cdot f_Z(z) dz \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f_{X|Y,Z}(x|y,z) \cdot f_{Y|Z}(y|z) \cdot f_Z(z) dx dy dz \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) dx dy dz \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x \cdot f_X(x) dx \\[2ex]
&= E(X)
\end{align}
$$
Now, going back to the original question:
$$ E[X] = E[E[X|\mu,\sigma]] $$
$$ E[X|\mu,\sigma] = \mu $$
$$ E[\mu] = \theta_1 $$
Using the Law of Total Expectations:
$$
\begin{align}
E[X] &= E[E[E[X|\mu,\sigma]|\mu]] \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E[E[X|\mu,\sigma]|\mu] f_\mu(\mu) d\mu \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} E[X|\mu,\sigma] f_\sigma(\sigma) d\sigma\right) f_\mu(\mu) d\mu \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mu f_\sigma(\sigma) d\sigma\right) f_\mu(\mu) d\mu \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mu \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f_\sigma(\sigma) d\sigma\right) f_\mu(\mu) d\mu \\[2ex]
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mu f_\mu(\mu) d\mu \\[2ex]
&= E[\mu] \\[2ex]
&= \theta_1
\end{align}
$$
2) Variance of X:
Here we can see the Law of Total Variance (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_variance)
$$
\begin{align}
Var(X) &= E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 
&= E[E[X^2|Y]] - (E[E[X|Y]])^2 
&= \int E[X^2|Y=y] \cdot Pr[Y=y] ~dy - \left(\int E[X|Y=y] \cdot Pr[Y=y] ~dy\right)^2 
&= \int (Var(X|Y=y) + (E[X|Y=y])^2) \cdot Pr[Y=y] ~dy - \left(\int E[X|Y=y] \cdot Pr[Y=y] ~dy\right)^2  
&= \int Var(X|Y=y) \cdot Pr[Y=y] ~dy + \int (E[X|Y=y])^2 \cdot Pr[Y=y] ~dy - (E[E[X|Y]])^2 
&= E[Var(X|Y)] + E[(E[X|Y])^2] - (E[E[X|Y]])^2 
&= E[Var(X|Y)] + Var(E[X|Y]) 
\end{align}
$$
I tried to extend it for a two variable problem:
$$
\begin{align}
Var(X) &= E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 
&= E[E[X^2|Y,Z]] - (E[E[X|Y,Z]])^2 
&= \iint E[X^2|Y=y,Z=z] \cdot Pr[Y=y,Z=z] dydz - \left(\iint E[X|Y=y,Z=z] \cdot Pr[Y=y,Z=z] dydz\right)^2 
&= \iint (Var(X|Y=y,Z=z) + (E[X|Y=y,Z=z])^2) \cdot Pr[Y=y,Z=z] dydz \
&\quad - \left(\iint E[X|Y=y,Z=z] \cdot Pr[Y=y,Z=z] dydz\right)^2  
&= \iint Var(X|Y=y,Z=z) \cdot Pr[Y=y,Z=z] dydz + \iint (E[X|Y=y,Z=z])^2 \cdot Pr[Y=y,Z=z] dydz \
&\quad - (E[E[X|Y,Z]])^2 \[2ex]
&= E[Var(X|Y,Z)] + E[(E[X|Y,Z])^2] - (E[E[X|Y,Z]])^2 
&= E[Var(X|Y,Z)] + Var(E[X|Y,Z])
\end{align}
$$
Start with the law of total variance:
$$ Var(X) = E_{\mu,\sigma}[Var(X|\mu,\sigma)] + Var_{\mu,\sigma}(E[X|\mu,\sigma]) $$
We can see that
$$ Var(X|\mu,\sigma) = \sigma^2 $$
$$ E[X|\mu,\sigma] = \mu $$
Substituting these into our original equation:
$$ Var(X) = E_{\mu,\sigma}[\sigma^2] + Var_{\mu,\sigma}(\mu) $$

Looking at: $E_{\mu,\sigma}[\sigma^2]$:

$$ E_{\mu,\sigma}[\sigma^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sigma^2 \cdot f_{\mu}(\mu) \cdot f_{\sigma}(\sigma) \, d\mu \, d\sigma $$
Due to independence of $μ$ and $σ$, the integral of $f(\sigma)$ from negative infinity to positive infinity becomes $1$. Thus,this simplifies to:
$$ E_{\mu,\sigma}[\sigma^2] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sigma^2 \cdot f_{\sigma}(\sigma) \, d\sigma = E[\sigma^2] $$
Since $Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2$, and since we predefined the expectation and variance of $ thus:
$$ E[\sigma^2] = Var(\sigma) + (E[\sigma])^2 = \theta_4^2 + \theta_3^2 $$

Looking at: $Var_{\mu,\sigma}(\mu)$.

In general, we know that:
$$\begin{align}
\text{Var}(X) &= E[(X - E(X))^2] \\[2ex]
&= E[X^2 - 2XE(X) + (E(X))^2] \\[2ex]
&= E[X^2] - E[2XE(X)] + E[(E(X))^2] \\[2ex]
&= E[X^2] - 2E[XE(X)] + (E(X))^2 \\[2ex]
&= E[X^2] - 2E(X)E[X] + (E(X))^2 \\[2ex]
&= E[X^2] - 2(E(X))^2 + (E(X))^2 \\[2ex]
&= E[X^2] - (E(X))^2
\end{align}$$
Thus, we can say:
$$ Var_{\mu,\sigma}(\mu) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\mu - E[\mu])^2 \cdot f_{\mu}(\mu) \cdot f_{\sigma}(\sigma) \, d\mu \, d\sigma $$
Again, due to independence of $μ$ and $σ$, the integral of $f(\sigma)$ from negative infinity to positive infinity becomes $1$. Thus, this simplifies to:
$$ Var_{\mu,\sigma}(\mu) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (\mu - E[\mu])^2 \cdot f_{\mu}(\mu) \, d\mu = Var(\mu) $$
In the original question, we defined:
$$ Var(\mu) = \theta_2^2 $$
Combining these results:
$$ Var(X) = E_{\mu,\sigma}[\sigma^2] + Var_{\mu,\sigma}(\mu) = (\theta_4^2 + \theta_3^2) + \theta_2^2 $$
3) Distribution of $X$
This is where I am getting stuck (Assuming I have done everything above correctly).
From first principles, I know I can write:
$$ f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x|\mu,\sigma) g(\mu) h(\sigma) d\mu d\sigma $$
$$ f(x|\mu,\sigma) = \frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) $$
$$ g(\mu) = \frac{1}{\theta_2\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{(\mu-\theta_1)^2}{2\theta_2^2}\right) $$
$$ h(\sigma) = \frac{1}{\theta_4\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{(\sigma-\theta_3)^2}{2\theta_4^2}\right) $$
Since $\sigma$ needs to be a positive quantity (i.e. variance can not be negative), we can use the absolute value to reformulate it as:

For positive values of $σ$, $|σ| = σ$, so $h(|σ|) = h(σ)$ when $σ > 0$.
For negative values of $σ$, $|σ| = -σ$, so $h(|σ|) = h(-σ)$ when $σ < 0$.
Thus in general : $h(|σ|)=h(σ)+h(−σ) ; σ≥0$

Using this subtitution :
$$h(|\sigma|) = \frac{1}{\theta_4\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[\exp\left(-\frac{(\sigma-\theta_3)^2}{2\theta_4^2}\right) + \exp\left(-\frac{(-\sigma-\theta_3)^2}{2\theta_4^2}\right)\right] \quad \text{for } \sigma \geq 0$$
$$(-\sigma-\theta_3)^2 = (-1)^2(\sigma+\theta_3)^2 = (\sigma+\theta_3)^2$$
$$h(|\sigma|) = \frac{1}{\theta_4\sqrt{2\pi}} \left[\exp\left(-\frac{(\sigma-\theta_3)^2}{2\theta_4^2}\right) + \exp\left(-\frac{(\sigma+\theta_3)^2}{2\theta_4^2}\right)\right] \quad \text{for } \sigma \geq 0$$
I am not sure if this can be further simplified.
Is this as far as we can go?
Thanks!
Note:
$$ f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x|\mu,\sigma) g(\mu) h(\sigma) d\mu d\sigma $$
will likely need to be numerically integrated to answer questions such as:
$$ P(a \leq X \leq b) = \int_a^b f_X(x) \, dx = \int_a^b \left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty} f(x|\mu,\sigma) g(\mu) h(\sigma) \, d\sigma \, d\mu\right) \, dx $$

Why do you not use the standard notation $\mathcal N (\mu, \sigma^2)$ instead of $\mathcal N (\mu, \sigma)$?

@Amir It's probably spinoff from popular software (e.g. Python, R, Mathematica) that parameterizes the univariate normal distributions that way, e.g. "NormalDistribution[μ,σ]".

@r.e.s. Nice point, Thanks! I think the second parameter $b$ in the notation $\mathcal N (a,b)$ is always considered the variance in any books and papers.

@Amir In statistics literature, I think that's the most common convention by far; OTOH, there are postings over on the Statistics SE saying "there are at least three different conventions for interpreting X∼N(a,b) as a normal random variable", so I guess it pays to be explicit.

@stats_noob You may like to know an alternative way of obtaining the moments of $X$: Write $X=\mu+\sigma Z_1,\ \mu=\theta_1+\theta_2 Z_2,\ \sigma=\theta_3+\theta_4 Z_3,$ where $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$ are i.i.d. $\mathcal N(0,1)$; so $X=\theta_1+\theta_2 Z_2+\theta_3 Z_1 +\theta_4 Z_3 Z_1$. Then $E(X)=\theta_1+\theta_2 E(Z_2)+\theta_3 E(Z_1) +\theta_4 E(Z_3 Z_1)=\theta_1$, and, using $V(\sum_i X_i)=\sum_i V(X_i)+2\sum_{i<j}\text{cov}(X_i,X_j)$, we also find $V(X)=\theta_2^2+\theta_3^2+\theta_4^2.$

@stats_noob (cont'd) Of course, it's inconsistent to model $\sigma$ (a std. dev.) as a r.v. that takes negative values; i.e., $Z_3$ should have some distribution with $P(Z_3<0)=0$.

@ Amir: thank you for this suggestion, I will keep this in mind!

@ res: thank you for your replies! If you have time, could you please post an answer about this? I realize my inconsistency involving $\sigma$ taking negative values ...

@stats_noob I've expanded the comment into an answer. BTW I only just happened to see your request: when you type @ res it fails to notify me because it must be without spaces but with the dots -- the system should bring up a list of matching usernames when you just type @<first letter>, e.g. @r .

If you agree that $\sigma>0$, then $\sigma$ cannot follow $N(\theta_3,\theta_4)$, which is supported on $\mathbb{R}$, rather than on $\mathbb{R}^+$. So the question setting has an issue that prevents finding a good answer.
From your third part, you might find it helpful to check the Folded Normal Distribution in order to update the question. (But there are many other easier priors for $\sigma$, if the purpose of this question is only for exercise. )
PS: However, this will not affect the "$\mathbb{E}(X)$" form you found.

@ Zack Fisher : Thanks for your answer... I think I understand what you mean...

Do you know if what I did here is correct? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4942863/general-rule-for-finding-out-a-probability-distribution

You may like to know an alternative way of obtaining the moments of $X$, noting that for your "hierarchical" model, the moments of $X$ depend only on the moments of the distributions, but not on any other specifics (assuming independence and that the distributions are in location-scale families):
Suppose
$$\begin{align}
X \sim \mathcal P_1(\mu, \sigma):&\quad\quad X=\mu+\sigma Z_1,\quad Z_1\sim\mathcal P_1(0,1)\\
\mu \sim \mathcal P_2(\theta_1, \theta_2):&\quad\quad \mu=\theta_1+\theta_2 Z_2,\quad Z_2\sim\mathcal P_2(0,1)\\
\sigma \sim \mathcal P_3(\theta_3, \theta_4):&\quad\quad \sigma=\theta_3+\theta_4 Z_3,\quad Z_3\sim\mathcal P_3(0,1)\\
\end{align}$$
where $Z_1,Z_2,Z_3$ are independent, and the parameters (expected value, standard deviation) are as stated, but the probability distributions $\mathcal P_1,\mathcal P_2,\mathcal P_3$ are otherwise unspecified$^\dagger$.
Then
$$\begin{align}
X&=(\theta_1+\theta_2\,Z_2)+(\theta_3+\theta_4\,Z_3)\,Z_1\\
X&=\theta_1+\theta_2Z_2+\theta_3Z_1+\theta_4Z_3Z_1\tag{0}\\
\end{align}$$
so
$$\begin{align}
E(X)&=\theta_1+\theta_2\,E(Z_2)+\theta_3\,E(Z_1)+\theta_4\,E(Z_3Z_1)=\theta_1\tag{1}\\[1ex]
V(X)&=\theta_2^2\,V(Z_1)+\theta_3^2\,V(Z_1)+\theta_4^2\,V(Z_3Z_1)=\theta_2^2+\theta_3^2+\theta_4^2\tag{2}\\
\end{align}$$
where (1) follows from the linearity of expectation, and $E(Z_i)=0$, with  $E(Z_3Z_1)=E(Z_3)\,E(Z_1)$ due to independence, while (2) follows from the general property
$$V\left(\sum_iX_i\right)=\sum_iV(X_i)+\sum_{i\ne j}\text{cov}(X_i,X_j)$$
with $$\text{cov}(X_i,X_j):=E(X_iX_j)-E(X_i)\,E(X_j)$$
since $V(Z_i)=1$ and $V(Z_3Z_1):=E(Z_3^2Z_1^2)-E(Z_3Z_1)^2=E(Z_3^2)\,E(Z_1^2)-0=V(Z_3)\,V(Z_1)=1,$
and here all the covariances vanish due to independence, noting that $E(Z_1\,Z_3Z_1)=E(Z_1^2\,Z_3)=0$.
$^\dagger$ Of course there is the implicit requirement that $\mathcal P_3(\theta_3, \theta_4)$ be such that $P(\sigma<0)=0$, since as a standard deviation $\sigma$ cannot be negative.
